# Random quote button works only once on clicking

Tags: reactjs

I have created a random quote machine project in React with functional component. When I click on new quote it works only once. This is one of the freecodecamp challenge project. Here, I am trying to get new quote every time I click on the new quote button. I am unable to spot the issue. Please help.

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {Button, Card, Col, Container, Row} from "react-bootstrap";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faTwitter } from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons";

const quotes = [
  {
    quote: "The greatest glory in living lies not in never falling, but in rising every time we fall.",
    author: "Nelson Mandela"
  },
  {
    quote: "The way to get started is to quit talking and begin doing.",
    author: "Walt Disney"
  },
  {
    quote: "Your time is limited, so don't waste it living someone else's life. Don't be trapped by dogma – which is living with the results of other people's thinking." ,
    author: "Steve Jobs"
  },
  {
    quote: "If life were predictable it would cease to be life, and be without flavor.",
    author: "Eleanor Roosevelt"
  },
  {
    quote: "If you look at what you have in life, you'll always have more. If you look at what you don't have in life, you'll never have enough.",
    author: "Oprah Winfrey"
  },
  {
    quote: "If you set your goals ridiculously high and it's a failure, you will fail above everyone else's success.",
    author: "James Cameron"
  },
  {
    quote: "Life is what happens when you're busy making other plans.",
    author: "John Lennon"
  },
  {
    quote: "Spread love everywhere you go. Let no one ever come to you without leaving happier.",
    author: "Mother Teresa"
  },
  {
    quote: "When you reach the end of your rope, tie a knot in it and hang on.",
    author: "Franklin D. Roosevelt"
  },
  {
    quote: "It is during our darkest moments that we must focus to see the light.",
    author: "Aristotle"
  },
];
const colors = [
  "#ffdecf",
  "#d3dbff",
  "#8fcfd1",
  "#eeecda",
  "#383e56",
  "#89c9b8",
  "#cff6cf",
  "#726a95",
  "#abc2e8",
  "#303960"
];

const rand_num = Math.floor(Math.random()*quotes.length);

export const Quoter = () => {

  const [quote, setQuote] = useState(quotes[0].quote);
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState(quotes[0].author);
  const [color, setColor] = useState(colors[0]);


  const handleQuote = () => {
    return (
      setQuote(quotes[rand_num].quote),
      setAuthor(quotes[rand_num].author),
      setColor(colors[rand_num])
    )
  }


  return (
    <Container id="quote-box">
      <Row className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <Card>
          <Card.Body style={{width: "18rem"}}>
            <Card.Text id="text" style={{color: color}}>
              {quote}
              <Col>
                <p id='author'>-{author}</p>
              </Col>
            </Card.Text>
                <Button id='tweet-quote'><Card.Link href=""><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTwitter}/></Card.Link></Button>
                <Button id='new-quote'
                        onClick={handleQuote}
                >
                  New Quote
                </Button>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at [ask]. Please clarify your problem and may use a [mcve].

Comment: @Hille OP provided *more* than a minimal example. They shared the *entire* component code, imports, and data, and stated the problem fairly clearly, that the random quote is chosen only once, and even provided a simple repro, and that finally they just can't see where the issue lies. The average SO user with much more experience often provides much less.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined `rand_num` outside the component, so it's computed only once. Move it into the `handleQuote` function callback so it's computed each time the callback is invoked. You also don't need to return anything from the handler, just update state.

```
const handleQuote = () => {
  const rand_num = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
  
  setQuote(quotes[rand_num].quote);
  setAuthor(quotes[rand_num].author);
  setColor(colors[rand_num]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @ Drew. Also I needed to replace comma with semicolon. Now, it's working fine.

Comment: @Drew, may I ask you to have a look at a react.js related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64067097/simple-html-element-in-react-js-code-does-not-work-in-xampp-localhost ?

Answer (score -1):

It would be much easier to simply make a list of quotes and when the button is pressed it will get a random value from the list.
as for your code, it looks fine tbh.